# How to retrieve drawable from attributes reference in a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, android-attributes

Can someone confirm what the correct way is to retrieve drawable from attributes reference (from a fragment)?

`activity.context` in `val myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity.context, imageResId) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot load drawable $imageResId")` returns this error:

> Unresolved reference: context

I'm unsure which context should be used here.

Here is some relevant code:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
activity!!.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.imgSearch, typedValue, true)
val imageResId = typedValue.resourceId
val myDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity.context, imageResId) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot load drawable $imageResId")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
activity.resources.getDrawable(imageResId)
```

Update: getDrawbale() is depricated from api 22, in that case you can try the following:

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity!!.resources, imageResId, null)
```

Comment: this was deprecated in API 22

Answer (score 4):

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(requireActivity().resources, R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_24, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of `Unresolved reference: context` is that there is no such `#getContext` method present with activity.

Since in `ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity.context, imageResId)` the `activity.context` would try to make a call to `activity#getContext`, since the method is not present, this exception is throw.

Try updating this statement to `ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, imageResId)` as activity is itself an instance of context.